# Array of Boolean are undefined when object dropped?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-droppable

I have some array of dragged object and dropped object, here:

```
var elmDragObj = ["#ob01","#ob02","#ob03","#ob04","#ob05","#ob06","#ob07","#ob08","#ob09","#ob10","#ob11","#ob12","#ob13","#ob14","#ob15","#ob16","#ob17","#ob18","#ob19","#ob20"];

var elmDropObj = ["#va_kb_a","#va_ks_a","#va_kk_a","#dk_kb_a","#dk_kb_b","#dk_ks_a","#pr_kb_a","#rv_kb_a","#rv_kb_b","#rv_kb_c","#pr_ks_a","#rv_ks_a","#rv_ks_b","#rv_ks_c","#vl_kb_a","#vl_ks_a","#vl_kk_a","#vk_kb_a","#vk_ks_a","#vk_kk_a"];
```

and i have array of booleans to check when all object are dropped in its place, here:

```
var elmBool = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];
```

when i want to check the boolean, it's undefined, script below:

```
for(var j=0; j<elmDragObj.length; j++){
        $(elmDragObj[j]).draggable({revert:"invalid"});

        $(elmDropObj[j]).droppable({
            accept: elmDragObj[j],
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                alert(elmBool[j]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: at the time that `drop` handler fires, it'll be trying to use the value that `j` ended up with at the **END** of the for() loop, not the value it had at the time the drop was defined. e.g. you're not embedding the at-that-particular-point-in-the-loop value of j.

Comment: is elmBool declared before the for loop? also, what happens if you only echo j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because by the time that...

```
alert(elmBool[j]);
```

... runs, `j` is now out of range for your array (it will be equal to `elmDragObj.length`).

The easiest solution is to simply use `$.each()`:

```
$.each(elmDragObj, function(j, sel) {
    $(sel).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });

    $(elmDropObj[j]).droppable({
        accept: sel,
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            alert(elmBool[j]);
        }
    });
});
```

If you really wanted to use a `for` loop, it can be done, but you'll need to "lock" the value of `j` in a closure:

```
for(var j=0; j<elmDragObj.length; j++){
    $(elmDragObj[j]).draggable({revert:"invalid"});

    $(elmDropObj[j]).droppable({
        accept: elmDragObj[j],
        drop: (function() {
            var index = j;
            return function(event, ui) {
                alert(elmBool[index]);
            };
        })()
    });
}
```

Clearly that's not as developer friendly as the first approach, though, so my recommendation is definitely to go with `$.each()`.

Comment: so.. how do i get the boolean value??
that just get the name of droppable object..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that variable j is invalid at the time the function is called.  You have already run the loop and j is not valid, it has incremented past the end of the array.